# Creating a tube from orbit collection

Tags: plotting, computational-geometry, envelope

I have a [data file](http://www.mediafire.com/file/9v9lq9bn3wlzjpw/mans_3D.out) which contains the $(x,y,z)$ coordinates of a large collection of orbits (about 2000 orbits). Now let's plot them

```
data1 = Import["mans_3D.out", "Table"];
d1 = SplitBy[data1, Dimensions][[2 ;; ;; 2]];
d11 = d1[[;; , ;; , {1, 2, 3}]];
d2 = Map[{1, -1, 1} # &, d11, {-2}];

g1 = Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[0.003], Line /@ d11}, Axes -> True, 
     BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotRange -> 15, ImageSize -> 550];
g2 = Graphics3D[{Darker[Green], PointSize[0.003], Line /@ d2}, 
     Axes -> True, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
     BoxStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.003]], PlotRange -> 15, 
     ImageSize -> 550];     

rmax = 25;
plot1 = Show[{g1, g2}, AxesStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 20,   
        FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
        PlotRange -> rmax, BoxStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.005]], 
        ImageSize -> 550, ViewPoint -> {1.5, -1.1, 1.5}]
```

which produces the following plot (the three dimensional gray surface it's not important)

[image]

As we can see, the orbits create three-dimensional tubes inside the $(x,y,z)$ configuration space. Below I present a zoom plot

[image]

Now I want the following: use the orbits as a guide in order to produce two hollow transparent tubes (red and green). The tubes should contain inside all the corresponding orbits and their shape should look like the following red tube

[image]

Is this task doable, using Mathematica, at all? And if so, how?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The dimensions of the data sets `{2222, 99, 3}`, so that's `2222` orbits of `99-1` line segments each?

Comment: @Feyre Yep, that's right!

Comment: It seems I found something that Mathematica can not do!

Comment: How do you expect anyone to write this program? You have not made the data available anywhere.

Comment: @bills I'm sorry but you are wrong! The complete data file is available through a hyperlink at the very first sentence of the post (data file in red).

Comment: OK -- thanks... I missed the link.

Comment: I'm confused, to say the least. This collection of orbits doesn't really resemble a torus.

Comment: For all would-be answerers, I found the following code quite fast and convenient to import this large dataset: ``strm = OpenRead["mans_3D.out"]; Do[ReadList[strm, "String", 1];
 orbit[i] = Developer`ToPackedArray@ReadList[strm, {Number, Number, Number}, 99];,{i, 2222}];Close[strm];``

Comment: @LLlAMnYP We have to take infinite amount of orbit so as to produce the exact torus. Now we have about 2000 orbits which do create to torus-like surface. The tricky part is to use these orbits as a guide in order to produce a hollow torus surface.

Comment: They do indeed create a *tube*, but not a torus (see all these self-intersecting spirals near the origin of the plot). Are you trying to find a generic tube with variable radius along its length, on the surface of which these orbits will lie?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Yes, I want to plot two hollow tubes which will contain inside all these orbits. The shape of the tubes should follow the path and the curvature of the guide-orbits. Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe, though decidely non-trivial. Can't stay at the computer for now, but I'll take a look when there's time.

Comment: If you wish to reconstruct a surface which represents the collection of all orbits, I don't think I can help. It is most certainly not a tube, a lot of background info will be needed here. I do, however, have some idea of how to get the general path, with help of some arc-length parametrization.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Something is better than nothing! Could you present the shape of this general path? Could we plot a tube along this path?

Comment: I think you are conceptually looking for the *medial axis transform* and/or *3D skeletonization* (maybe with the "Mean Curvature Skeleton" algorithm).

Answer (score 5):

This is a partial answer in response to Vaggelis' comment.

First, importing the data:

```
strm = OpenRead["mans_3D.out"];
Do[ReadList[strm, "String", 1];
orbit[i] = Developer`ToPackedArray@ReadList[strm, {Number, Number, Number}, 99],
{i, 2222}]
Close[strm];
```

Next, sort each orbit by their lengths:

```
Evaluate[sorted/@Range[2222]] = SortBy[orbit/@Range[2222], Total[Norm /@ Differences[#]] &]
```

Some orbits seem to be localized near the origin, but approximately from `sorted[1300]` and upwards they all lie on the larger almost circular arms visible in OPs first figure.

First parametrize the longest orbit by arc-length:

```
parametrized[2222] =
 Interpolation[{First@#, Rest@#} & /@ 
   Transpose[{{0.}~Join~
       Accumulate[(Norm /@ Differences@sorted[2222])]}~Join~
     Transpose@sorted[2222]]]
```

Then parametrize the rest by arc-length, using the i+1'th orbit as an approximation for the i'th if we go out of range of the arc-length:

```
Do[parametrized[i] =
  Interpolation[{First@#, Rest@#} & /@ 
    Transpose[{{0.}~Join~Accumulate[(Norm /@ Differences@sorted[i])]}~
      Join~Transpose@sorted[i]], 
   "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {parametrized[i + 1], 
     "WarningMessage" -> False}],
 {i, 2221, 1300, -1}]
```

I *assume* and this answer relies on that if you go 20 "steps" along one orbit, say `sorted[1500]`, you'll find yourself roughly in the same place if you follow `sorted[2000]` for the same 20 "steps". In that case, the general path of the collection of orbits is given by

```
Mean[Through[(parametrized /@ Range[1302, 1500])[x]]]
```

And this can be plotted by

```
Table[Mean[Through[(parametrized /@ Range[1302, 2222])[x]]], {x, 0, 47.4, .5}]
Graphics3D[Line@%]
```

This is far from perfect, but a starting point, nonetheless.

**UPDATE**
My thought about the phase space appears to have been useful. The following code:

```
strm = OpenRead["mans_3D.out"];
Do[ReadList[strm, "String", 1];
 orbit[i] = 
  Developer`ToPackedArray@
   ReadList[strm, {Number, Number, Number}, 99], {i, 2222}]
Close[strm];
Do[xyz[i] = (Rest@# + Most@#)/2 &@orbit[i], {i, 2222}]
Do[pxyz[i] = Differences@orbit[i], {i, 2222}]
Manipulate[
 ListPlot[Table[{xyz[j][[i, k]], pxyz[j][[i, l]]}, {j, 2222}]], {i, 1,
   98, 1}, {k, 1, 3, 1}, {l, 1, 3, 1}]
```

Basically, it plots the k-th component of the midpoint of the i-th line segment in every orbit against the length of the projection of said line segment on the l-th axis.

Comment: I run your code but the result is just a line in 3D space which does not follow the full path of the manifolds. I suppose that producing 3D fitting tubes would be impossible, right?

Comment: Like I said, this solution is based on several assumptions. Without much knowledge of the underlying problem its not that easy to take meaningful steps to solve this. Another idea that comes to mind is to plot the phase space. But here the underlying assumption is that the positions on all the orbits are sampled at 99 equally spaced points in time.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z I've added the code for visualizing the phase-space, though I cannot say it really helps much in solving the problem, rather highlights its difficulty.